# labeling edges in tikz using boxes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I'm creating labels for edges by manually creating a node and placing it in the center of the edge. Is there a cleaner way to do it? Also I would like to have the edge invisible inside the label.

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[    transform shape]
        \newcommand\XA{-3}
        \newcommand\YA{0}
        \node (x) [circle, draw=black, align=center, minimum size=1cm] at (\XA,\YA) {$V$};
        \node (y) [circle, draw=black, align=center, minimum size=1cm   ] at (\XA-1.5,\YA-1.5) {$U$};
        \node (l1) [thin, draw=black, align=center, minimum width=0.5cm, minimum height=0.5cm] at(\XA-0.75,\YA-0.75) {\Large d};
        \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
        (x) edge[->] node {} (y);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `fill=white`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape,mylabel/.style={thin, draw=black, align=center, minimum width=0.5cm, minimum height=0.5cm,fill=white,font=\Large}]
        \newcommand\XA{-3}
        \newcommand\YA{0}
        \node (x) [circle, draw=black, align=center, minimum size=1cm] at (\XA,\YA) {$V$};
        \node (y) [circle, draw=black, align=center, minimum size=1cm   ] at (\XA-1.5,\YA-1.5) {$U$};
        \draw[->]  (x) -- node[mylabel] {d} (y);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`\centering` doesn't take an argument, hence `{...}` are not needed. Also, `edge` is a monster, don't use it for small things.

Comment: perfect. Thank you. This is much cleaner than my approach.